# Create Custom Seekbar Programmatically (No XML)

Tags: android, seekbar

Currently I am trying to create a custom Seekbar without using xml as the images for the background and progress bar need to be changed. This is what I have at the moment:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(appState.images.get(Integer.parseInt(image)));   
this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(appState.images.get(Integer.parseInt(image_a)));    
this.setProgressDrawable(drawable2);

this.setProgress(0);
```

But the progressDrawable is just set to the entire size of Seekbar and when I move the thumb from side to side nothing happens. Does anybody have any ideas as I am completely stumped.

Comment: Do you need to change the graphics at runtime,or just from the standard?

Comment: They have to be changed at runtime as the images are downloaded and stored then used to create display on views.

Comment: The custom seekbar xml I use makes use of the "clip" tag around the progess drawable. I'm not exactly sure how it operates, but I know I know the seekbar malfunctions without it. I believe clipDrawable can be achieved programmatically.  I'll have a look. For reference, here is my xml: `<item
  android:id="@android:id/progress">
  <clip>
   <shape>
       <solid
           android:color="@color/highlight" />
   </shape>
  </clip>
 </item>`

Comment: It's far from pretty, but this looks like your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158831/changing-the-size-of-the-seekbar-programmatically-but-cant-get-the-thumb-to-be-l

Comment: Ah yes, that's perfect thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this previous answer does the trick for you:

[Changing the size of the seekbar programmatically but cant get the thumb to be larger than the bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158831/changing-the-size-of-the-seekbar-programmatically-but-cant-get-the-thumb-to-be-l)

From the original asker:

> In the end I am using this code:

```
public void setSeekBarImages(){
    Drawable drawable = new
             BitmapDrawable(appState.images.get(Integer.parseInt(image_a)));
    ClipDrawable clip = new ClipDrawable(drawable,
             Gravity.LEFT,ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    Drawable drawable2 = new
             BitmapDrawable(appState.images.get(Integer.parseInt(image))); 
    InsetDrawable d1= new InsetDrawable(drawable2,5,5,5,5);
    //the padding u want to use
    setThumb(null);
    LayerDrawable mylayer = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{d1,clip});
    setProgressDrawable(mylayer);
    setProgress(0);
}
```