# Create progressDrawable programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, colors, drawable, progress

I want to change the appearance on my progress bar dynamically using the `setProgressDrawable` method, and without involving xml files.

I saw this answer : [Create a progress drawable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011075/create-a-progress-drawable-programmatically) ,but some reason, it sets only the progress background color. The actual progress color does not even appear. Is what I'm doing right?

My code:

```
public static LayerDrawable createDrawable(int accentColor, int backColor) {

    ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable();
    shape.getPaint().setStyle(Style.FILL);
    shape.getPaint().setColor(backColor);

    ShapeDrawable shapeD = new ShapeDrawable();
    shapeD.getPaint().setStyle(Style.FILL);
    shapeD.getPaint().setColor(accentColor);
    ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(shapeD, Gravity.LEFT,
            ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {
             clipDrawable });
    return layerDrawable;
}
```

Setting a new drawable

```
progressBar[i].setProgress(Integer.parseInt(internal_marks[i]));
progressBar[i].setProgressDrawable(createDrawable(accent_list[mIndex],getResources().getColor(R.color.progressBack)));
```

FYI: It works fine if I use a xml instead of creating a drawable synamically, but I want to do it dynamically.

Comment: can't you use Drawable.setColorFilter ?

Comment: @pskink I just want to change color of the Pbar, how do i use setColorFilter? Havent used it before.. Please guide..

Comment: if you just want to change the color setColorFilter will do the trick

Comment: @pskink Could you please post the method as an answer? I am quite new to android programming..